# Sending messages from background thread to main thread in a number crunching application

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a number crunching application in Delphi that uses one or more background threads to process numerical data. These background threads run several parallel processes each simultaneously. From these threads I use the WM_COPYDATA message to pass information to the main thread, in order to provide feedback to the users.

In my PC I have the Intel Core i7-10750H CPU processor (6 physical cores and 12 threads) and my RAM is 32GB.
When I run one or two analyses simultaneously (CPU usage 50- 80%, memory consumption 1-2GB) , the messages are passed and processed by the main thread correctly, i.e., I get the feedback in the GUI of the main form. However, when I push the  system to its limits (6 parallel analyses in a PC with 6 physical cores, CPU usage > 90%, memory consumption > 2.5GB), very often the messages are not passed to the main thread and I get no feedback in the GUI (somehow they seem to be lost). However, the background threads run correctly and at the end of the analyses they provide the correct results.

What is the problem and the messages are not processed? Can I do something to fix this problem?
Many thanks in advance.

The data are passed with the following record:

```
type
  TCommunicationMsgRecord = record
    AnalysisID: integer;
    UpdateType: integer;
    MessageStr: String[255];
    prbProgress: integer;
    valX,valY: real;
  end;
```

The code in the background thread is the following:

```
procedure TExecution.SetMainFormMemoProcess(const str: string);
var
  CommunicationMsgRecord: TCommunicationMsgRecord;
  copyDataStruct : TCopyDataStruct;
begin
      CommunicationMsgRecord.AnalysisID := Self.ExecutionID;
      CommunicationMsgRecord.UpdateType := 0;
      CommunicationMsgRecord.MessageStr := StrLeft(str,255);
      CommunicationMsgRecord.prbProgress := 0;
      CommunicationMsgRecord.valX := 0;
      CommunicationMsgRecord.valY := 0;
      //------------------------------------------------------
      copyDataStruct.dwData := 0;
      copyDataStruct.cbData := SizeOf(CommunicationMsgRecord);
      copyDataStruct.lpData := @CommunicationMsgRecord;
      SendMessage(MainForm.handle, WM_COPYDATA, Integer(hInstance), Integer(@copyDataStruct));
end;
```

The code in the main thread is the following:

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure WMCopyData( var Msg : TWMCopyData ); message WM_COPYDATA;

implementation
procedure TMainForm.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
  CommunicationMsgRecord : TCommunicationMsgRecord;
begin
    try
        CommunicationMsgRecord:= TCommunicationMsgRecord(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData^);
        case CommunicationMsgRecord.UpdateType of
           0: MainForm.memoProcess.Lines.Add(CommunicationMsgRecord.MessageStr);
           1: MainForm.Statusbar.Panels[0].Text := CommunicationMsgRecord.MessageStr;
           //other options (e.g. plotting) that receive the data from CommunicationMsgRecord
           //....
        end;
    except
          on E: EAccessViolation do
           begin
              ShowMessage('Access Violation');
           end;
           on E: Exception do //this will catch all your other exceptions
           begin
              ShowMessage('Other Error');
           end;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Never catch `EAccessViolation`. That's one of the most serious exception you can get, and something that should never every happen in your app. Well written code should never raise such an exception. It should be mathematically impossible (at least if you disregard malfunctioning hardware, OS bugs, hardware driver bugs etc.). In addition, you are never guaranteed to get an AV exception: sometimes you get no exception at all, but memory corruption that may or may not manifest itself in the future. (Maybe you'll send an incorrect $15651233213 invoice a week later.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, using `WM_COPYDATA` is overkill in this situation.  It is meant for serializing data across process boundaries, which you are not doing.  Since you are sending data to a window in the same process, just send the data pointer directly in a custom message.

Also, do not use `Integer()` type-casts, that will only work in 32-bit. If you ever decide to compile your app for 64-bit (ie, to access more memory), the code shown *will* fail.  The 4th parameter of `SendMessage()` is an `LPARAM`, not an `Integer`.  `LPARAM` is a 32bit or 64bit integer, depending on the CPU architecture. Use the proper type.

```
type
  PCommunicationMsgRecord = ^TCommunicationMsgRecord;
  TCommunicationMsgRecord = record
    AnalysisID: integer;
    UpdateType: integer;
    MessageStr: String[255];
    prbProgress: integer;
    valX,valY: real;
  end;

const
  WM_MY_DATA_MSG = WM_APP + 100;

procedure TExecution.SetMainFormMemoProcess(const str: string);
var
  CommunicationMsgRecord: TCommunicationMsgRecord;
begin
  CommunicationMsgRecord.AnalysisID := Self.ExecutionID;
  CommunicationMsgRecord.UpdateType := 0;
  CommunicationMsgRecord.MessageStr := StrLeft(str,255);
  CommunicationMsgRecord.prbProgress := 0;
  CommunicationMsgRecord.valX := 0;
  CommunicationMsgRecord.valY := 0;

  SendMessage(MainForm.Handle, WM_MY_DATA_MSG, 0, LPARAM(@CommunicationMsgRecord));
end;

...

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure WMMyDataMsg( var Msg : TMessage ); message WM_MY_DATA_MSG;
    ...
  end;

procedure TMainForm.WMMyDataMsg(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  CommunicationMsgRecord : PCommunicationMsgRecord;
begin
  try
    CommunicationMsgRecord := PCommunicationMsgRecord(Msg.LParam);
    case CommunicationMsgRecord.UpdateType of
      0: MainForm.MemoProcess.Lines.Add(CommunicationMsgRecord.MessageStr);
      1: MainForm.StatusBar.Panels[0].Text := CommunicationMsgRecord.MessageStr;
      //....
    end;
  except
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Second, using `MainForm.Handle` the way you are is not thread-safe.  The VCL *can* (and sometimes does) recreate its `HWND`s dynamically at runtime.  If you happen to read a `Handle` property in a worker thread at the same time that the VCL is re-creating that property's `HWND`, really bad things can happen.  You should use a separate `HWND` that is guaranteed to be persistent, such as `TApplication.Handle` (use `TApplication.HookMainWindow()` to receive its messages), or better the result of `AllocateHWnd()`.

Now, with that said, if you are sending a lot of messages to the main thread, you are probably filling up the main thread's message queue. The queue can hold only so many messages at a time (IIRC, the limit is 10000), but the code you have shown is not performing any error checking on the `SendMessage()` call, eg:.

```
procedure TExecution.SetMainFormMemoProcess(const str: string);
var
  ...
  ErrCode: DWORD;
begin
  ...
  if SendMessage(...) = 0 then
  begin
    ErrCode := GetLastError();
    if ErrCode = ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA then
      // the message queue is full ...
  end;
end;
```

Also, note that `SendMessage()` is synchronous, it does not return until the message handler processes the message, which means your worker threads will synchronize against each other, slowing down their processing since one thread will have to wait on another thread if they try to send their data at the same time.  To avoid that, use `PostMessage()` instead (and dynamically allocate the data being posted) so that your threads can run at their full speed, eg:

```
procedure TExecution.SetMainFormMemoProcess(const str: string);
var
  CommunicationMsgRecord: PCommunicationMsgRecord;
begin
  New(CommunicationMsgRecord);
  CommunicationMsgRecord.AnalysisID := Self.ExecutionID;
  CommunicationMsgRecord.UpdateType := 0;
  CommunicationMsgRecord.MessageStr := StrLeft(str,255);
  CommunicationMsgRecord.prbProgress := 0;
  CommunicationMsgRecord.valX := 0;
  CommunicationMsgRecord.valY := 0;

  if not PostMessage(MainForm.Handle, WM_MY_DATA_MSG, 0, LPARAM(CommunicationMsgRecord)) then
  begin
    Dispose(CommunicationMsgRecord);
    ...
  end;
end;

...

procedure TMainForm.WMMyDataMsg(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  CommunicationMsgRecord : PCommunicationMsgRecord;
begin
  try
    CommunicationMsgRecord := PCommunicationMsgRecord(Msg.LParam);
    try
      ...
    finally
      Dispose(CommunicationMsgRecord);
    end;
  except
    ...
  end;
end;
```

But, be careful, because that is likely to fill up the main thread's message queue even faster, so instead you should consider storing your data results elsewhere in thread-safe memory, and then have the main thread display the latest results at regular intervals (say, in a timer) rather than on every individual data update.

Comment: Many thanks for the very detailed response. I applied all your suggestions successfully, and things seem to be working fine. I only have a couple of final doubts:

Comment: 1) When using PostMessage, with ‘dynamically allocate the data being posted’ (as you suggested), you mean to allocate the memory for the record in the background thread and free it in the main thread after the data have been read, right?

2) My initial code worked when compiled as a 64-bit app, it did not fail even if the Integer type-cast was wrong. Could this is because the integer has the same size in 32-bit and 64-bit?

3) In order to access the Application handle from the background threads I had to declare in the uses vcl.forms. This is not a problem, right?

Comment: If the 64 bit address that needs to be accessed happens to have the top 32 bit all zeros then bad code that zeros out those bits by using a 32 bit intermediate value won't crash. Soon as those bits are not zeros you get crashes / memory corruption etc.

Comment: @SteliosAntoniou: `Integer` is always a 32-bit integer, both in a 32-bit app and a 64-bit app. So in a 32-bit app, a pointer will always fit in an `Integer`, but in a 64-bit app, a pointer will in general NOT fit in an `Integer`. But it may accidentally do that. For example, if the pointer value is `$00000000 003D1ABB`, then truncating it to an `Integer`, you get `$003D1ABB`. Interpreting this as a pointer, you get `$00000000 003D1ABB` back and everything is fine. However, if the pointer happens to be `$03CDBA38 113D1ABB` then you get `$113D1ABB` as an `Integer` and interpreting this back...

Comment: ...as a pointer, you get `$00000000 113D1ABB` which is a completely different part of your computer's memory. So reading or writing from this address (incorrectly believing it to be the original one) will cause bugs and crashes or random misbehaviour a week later. Now, it so happened that most pointers even in 64-bit apps used to start with a lot of zeros until ASLR was implemented, so a few years ago, your app often worked "on most systems most of the time" without any visible issues. (But if you had been writing software for pacemakers, you would have killed a patient or two.) Now...

Comment: ...with ASLR (like in Delphi 11.3), you are much more likely to see truncated pointers and memory corruption and crashes, maybe almost every time you run the program.

Comment: @SteliosAntoniou 1) Yes, as I showed in my example. 2) What Andrea said. 3) If you access `Application` directly, then you need `Vcl.Forms`, yes. But your thread doesn't need to access `Application` directly. The main thread could pass `Application.Handle` (or `MainForm.Handle`, or the `AllocateHwnd()` result) as an input parameter to the worker thread's constructor and store it in a member of your thread class. You just need the `HWND`, not the whole `Application` object.